# deduct 60 minutes/ 1 hour from punch time (Start time) of attendance

Tags: sql-server

Suppose there are 300 employees different kinds of shifting duty they are doing but on 15th October Fingertec machine's clock was stop, so now I want to deduct 60 minutes or 1 hour from their in time. How can I update this in SQL query? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? If you share your table structure the answer could be more precise.

```
-- TEST TABLE
CREATE TABLE dbo.employees(id int identity(1,1), 
                           StartTime datetime2);

-- TEST VALUE
INSERT INTO dbo.employees (StartTime)
VALUES(getdate());

--CHECK
SELECT * FROM dbo.employees;

-- ACTUAL UPDATE
UPDATE dbo.employees
SET StartTime = DATEADD(hour,-1,StartTime);

-- CHECK AFTER UPDATE
SELECT * FROM dbo.employees;
```